# Upload file using php move_uploaded_file to two level upper folder

Tags: php

My script is in http://localhost/Website/admin/pages/scrip.php and I want to move my uploaded file to http://localhost/Website/images/folder. Is it possible to upload file to given location? If yes, then how. Thanks in advance...

Comment: This question is liable to **downvotes** and being **on hold**: We couldn't reproduce the PHP script even when using view page source.

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute paths at the second parameter of the move_uploaded_file function, example:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempfile,"/path/to/Website/images/folder/image.jpg")
```

or using relative paths, example:

```
move_uploaded_file($tempfile,"../../images/folder/image.jpg")
```